# How to disable page jump to top on $location params change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to set URL `preview` param by $location.search without page jump

I have tried to remove anchor from url:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
```

My URL looks like `http://local.website.com:9001/?preview=8d423aec`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use reloadOnSearch=false in your route definition. Please check following link for more details.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: reloadOnSearch is set to false, page is not reloading, but jumping with every location change

Comment: Does it jumps to the top of the page? If yes try disabling anchorScroll using $anchorScrollProvider.disableAutoScrolling()

Comment: i added `$anchorScrollProvider.disableAutoScrolling()` to my router config, but page still jumps, then i tried to use `$location.hash` istead of `$location.search` but problem still exist